# Software for Shas-like commentary

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I am looking for word processing software where one can have main text in middle and commentaries on the sides and bottom similar to the talmud, mishna or shulchan aruch layout.

Should be able to adjust automatically and provide a way to cross link commentaries to the main text.

Answer (score 2):

If you are **very** technically inclined, you can try LaTeX:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/how-to-typeset-a-complex-layout-like-a-page-of-the-talmud

(If you are not familiar with LaTeX, it is programming, not a Word-style software. It has a pretty steep learning curve.)

Comment: I am an experienced LaTEX user and have played around with the files used in the answers in the TeX.SE question. Each line length has to be set individually. So while it makes beautiful pages they are hand crafted.